# How can i know that a pipeline is using a microsoft hosted agent when running a pipeline?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

In the project i'm working on, when i run some of the pipelines, they are configure to use by default an old agent pool that supposedly doesn't exist anymore.

If i go to `Project settings > Agent pools` i don't see it there anymore.

My question is if when i run the pipeline

[image]

If there is any place i can use to tell if the pipeline is using a self-hosted or microsoft-hosted agent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer of @VinceBowdren gives an hint how we can get information about the agent of the running pipeline.

But specifically about the agent pools asked in the question, "Hosted" and "Hosted VS2017", they are deprecated microsoft hosted agents. Thats the reason they dont appear anymore in the agent pools list.

Pipelines that are configured using this agent pools will still be able to use them, but as soon as we save the pipeline to use another agent pool, it will not be possible to use them ever again.

We can confirm that these agent pools were deprecated here
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/2019/sprint-155-update#single-hosted-pool

Answer (score 2):

The pipeline logs show you which pool and which agent are being used:

[image: "Initialize job" pipeline log]

> Starting: Initialize job
> Agent name: 'ReleaseServerB-A002'
> Agent machine name: 'ReleaseServerB'
> Current agent version: '2.195.2'

Comment: Thanks for the answer thats the place we can get the information. Specifically, if there is a place were we can be sure if the pipeline is hosted or self hosted i guess we need to trace it back into the agent pools or the names when they run, we can use the screen you provided. Hosted and Hosted VS2017 are old hosted agent pools of microsoft that we cant choose anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml)  Agent.Name If you want to write out or do something specific according to the agent.

Answer (score 0):

As previous answers highlighted - you can use `Agent.Name` variable name.

In addition, if you want to perform some custom action for your Microsoft-hosted agent only you can do it like in the example below:

```
    - script: |
        echo "Agent.Name = $(Agent.Name)"
        pip install poetry
      displayName: Run only on Azure hosted VM
      condition: eq(variables['Agent.Name'], 'Hosted Agent')
```